# Javascript: getting the width of an img element

Tags: javascript, html, css

Using Javascript I have been able to select an image element (an `HTMLImageElement` object, say `img1`) in my html document. I can also get its style using `img1.style`. However, the following returns a blank alert:

`alert(img1.style.width);`

whereas this used in the same position works fine:

`alert(img1.width);`

so I don't think it's a problem with the image not having loaded yet.

I can *set* the width using either of the two options, though, and I like using the first, of course. But why can't I *get* the width using the first?

It's not so much the task I want to accomplish that's the issue here (I can do that in the second way); I want to learn what's wrong with the first way.

Comment: Depending on the size of the project, it might be usefull to use jQuery's `width()` function, so you don't have to worry about all this!

Comment: You are probably right. But it's not a huge project yet, and I wanted to stick to pure javascript and get some more practise coding the hard way before considering jQuery.

Comment: Good call! Yeah I agree, sometimes jQuery can be a little too much for a small project. But if there's a similar problem in a larger project, jQuery would solve this (and likely a bunch of other problems you're likely to be having)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`img1.style.width` returns the value of the css-attribute `width`. If you don't have a css rule that applies a width to that image, the property is an empty string.

Comment: This is probably it. However, the thought had crossed my mind. I had a specification for the `height` in the css, and I think I got a blank alert for that too. I'll check again and get back.

Comment: @Abhranil: more specifically, `.style.width` represents the *inline* style attribute for an element.  If you set `width` in a separate stylesheet, it will still be missing for `img1.style.width`.

Comment: Okay, that's greatly illuminating! Also very inconvenient :-( In that case, how would one go about fetching the style?

Comment: @AbhranilDas, this might be 2 years late... I ran into the same problem, and I found your comment here and [another response](http://www.cjboco.com/blog.cfm/post/determining-an-elements-width-and-height-using-javascript).  That other response worked for my issue, which was finding the width of a div.

Answer (score 1):

These are references to two different ways of setting an `<img>` width:

- You can set in in the HTML attributes, through `<img width="100px">` for example.
- You can set it for a style or a class that your `<img>` will belong to, through CSS.

The first one is accessed through `img.width`.
The second one through `img.style.width`.

Comment: This is essentially what Simon said in [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8878481/447356).

Comment: True, but my problem here is why one of these ways failed.

Comment: Where are you setting the img width ? If it's through the width="" html attribute, there won't be any width defined in the style linked to your img tag, hence the blank alert.

Comment: The width is specified in a separate CSS file, so it's part of `style`.